# Check for Not Matching words between strings

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a code that will output all the matching words in both strings if you log **words1[i]**.I changed the code a little bit to check for not matching words with no success. let's assume we have two strings:

```
var str1 = "world is beautiful";
var str2 = "is world butiful";
```

Then the output of the code will be (on console):

(2) ["is", "beautiful"]

(2) ["world", "beautiful"]

**How we can log Not Matching words between strings?**

The output should be an array of results, something like:

[beautiful]

Here is what I've tried:

```
var str1 = "world is beautiful";
var str2 = "is world bautiful";

var words1 = str1.split(/\s+/g),
    myArray = str1.split(/\s+/g),
    words2 = str2.split(/\s+/g),
    i,
    j;

for (i = 0; i < words1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < words2.length; j++) {
        if (words1[i].toLowerCase() == words2[j].toLowerCase()) {

        output = myArray.filter( ( el ) => !words1[i].includes( el ) );
        console.log(output);   

        }
    }
}
```

It seems because **words1[i]** is not an **array** the whole code doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow the same values multiple times in the result you could use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let a = "sent erth protect it".split(' ');
let b = "sent to earth to protect it".split(' ');
let res = b.filter(i => !a.includes(i));
console.log(res);
```

Or as pointed out by @Dhananjai Pai, creating a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and use [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)  to check if the key has a value of `true`:

```js
let map = new Map();
"sent erth protect it".split(' ').forEach(x => map.set(x, true));
let res = "sent to earth to protect it".split(' ').filter(x => !map.get(x));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can I include repeated words? let's say if our strings were var str1 = "sent erth protect it"; 
var str2 = "sent to earth to protect it"; we wanted [to,earth,to] not [to,earth] ???

Comment: @SaraRee I have added an update to my answer using includes.

Comment: The complexity here is O(mn) where m is the size of b and n is the size of a. It wastes so much computation for the lookup. It can be done is O(m) with the other method. To compare, if the strings each have 100 words. This method takes O(10000) comparisons where as a lookup takes only O(100).

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I have updated my answer using a Map. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but to rephrase your question, you want to make two arrays, one of matching words and another of not matching words.

For optimum performance, you can create a hashmap of sorts with the words of the first string and see if the words of the second string are in the map and add to either of result arrays accordingly.

You can use simple objects or Map in JavaScript to mock the hashmap structure. The below code only lists the noMatchWords array. If you want both matchWords and noMatchWords in the same loop, use a `reduce` method and push word to an accumulator object with the two arrays instead

```
let str1= 'world is beautiful' , str2 = 'is world butiful';
wordMap = str1.split(' ').reduce((map,word) => { map[word.toLowerCase()] = true; return map; },{});
noMatchWords = str2.split(' ').filter(word => !wordMap[word.toLowerCase()]);
console.log(noMatchWords) // prints ['butiful'] since it is not in the first string. You can replace str1 and str2 in the steps 2 and 3 if you want to print words in str1 and not in str2 ie, get ['beautiful']
```

Comment: Something wired happened. if I have this: let str1= 'I Was' , str2 = 'I was'; the not matching output will be "I"

Comment: @Sara Ree but `let str1= 'I was' , str2 = 'I Was'; wordMap = str1.split(' ').reduce((map,word) => { map[word.toLowerCase()] = true; return map; },{}); noMatchWords = str2.split(' ').filter(word => !wordMap[word.toLowerCase()]); console.log(noMatchWords)` works as expected for me